Athena unload lowercases all camelCase columns in parquet
I am using Athena UNLOAD query to unload results of SELECT in parquet format. I have columns in snake_case in Athena Table. So I did SELECT snake_case as snakeCase .. in my query.
The problem is I see all the Column in unload parquet files area lowercased. It seems ATHENA UNLOAD Command does not care about the case and lower case every column.
Example Query :
UNLOAD ( SELECT abc_de AS  abcDe, fgh_ij AS fghIj FROM 
        tablename  WHERE fgh_ij IN ( '123','456' ) and year = 2024 and month = 06 and day = 24
) 
TO 's3://dummy-bucketf2e78a99-gfm8/athena/data/test/' 
WITH (format='PARQUET', compression='None')

Is there any workaround or any parameter which I am missing here ?

Just guessing, but can you try SELECT abc_de as "abcDe" (in quotation marks)?

I tried that but it did not work
